# check is the value exists in array Google Sheets scripting?

Tags: scripting

I need to check if the certain value exists in both arrays and if exists remove this element from the second array. I know that it exists.

taking the 1st element from array doubleTue,  taking the index where is this value in amTue and pmTue then remove those by using splice command.

But now my code is having problem on getting the first value.

tried as in level array: `var val = doubleTue[i]`
and 2 level array: `var val - doubleTue[i][0]`

tried `toString()`, `read()`

```
    for (var n=0; n<doubleTue.length; n++)
    {
      var val = doubleTue[i][0];
      var val1 = amTue.indexOf(val);
      if (val1!=-1) {amTue.splice(val1, 1);};
      var val2=pmTue.indexOf(val);
      if (val2!=-1) {pmTue.splice(val2, 1); };
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue is found. i have used wrong variable for looping. hehe. copy past issue
thnks all